# Char to uint8 incorrect on microcontroller explanation?

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion, microcontroller

I am working on a project on a SAME70 Microcontroller. I had the need to convert from char to uint8_t. I was verifying that it was doing this correctly.

I noticed that when I ran this code to print out the final product:

```
char test[] = "hey this is a message from the MCU which I can make as large as I want it to be";

int main ( void )
{
    /* Initialize all modules */
    SYS_Initialize ( NULL );
    USART1_Write((uint8_t*)test, sizeof((uint8_t*)test));
}
```

The data printed out is incorrect. Only the first word "hey" gets printed. However, if I do this instead:

```
char test[] = "hey this is a message from the MCU which I can make as large as I want it to be";
uint8_t test2[79];
int sizedata = 0;

int main ( void )
{
    /* Initialize all modules */
    SYS_Initialize ( NULL );
    sizedata = sizeof(test);
    memcpy(test2,test,sizedata);
    USART1_Write(test2, sizeof(test2));
```

the conversion works correctly and everything gets printed. In both cases I gave it the same type as an input so it seems to me that the conversion isn't happening correctly. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof((uint8_t*)test)` is wrong. This is the size of a pointer `uint8_t*`. You should pass the size of the array `sizeof(test)` instead.

Also

```
uint8_t test2[79];

sizedata = sizeof(test);
memcpy(test2,test,sizedata);
```

is wrong. The string in the array `test` is 79-character long, so the array has 80 elements including the terminating null-character and therefore `sizeof(test)` is 80. On the other hand, the destination `test2` has only 79 bytes. Therefore this `memcpy` performs dangerous out-of-range access.

You should use

```
uint8_t test2[sizeof(test)];
```

instead. Or if you perfer to use magic numbers (I don't recommend this), you should write

```
sizedata = 79;
```

instead of

```
sizedata = sizeof(test);
```